# Changing file initally opened by xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am running xCode 6. While updating one of my older apps for iOS8, I switched to one of the xib files. xCode immediately crashed. This would be fine, except now everytime I open xCode, it tried to open the exact same xib and crashes again. I filed a report with Apple and can wait to hear back on that. But, I have other files I need to modify in xCode, so is there any way to change the file xCode initially opens when opening a project?

I checked in the pbxproj file and couldn't find a config for it

Comment: Have you deleted the derived data: "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/"? There was a crash message right? Want to share it? Want help? You will need to provide more information.

Comment: Did `git status` show any changes?  If so do `git checkout .` to revert any changes made by Xcode 6.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/22792251#22792251 . Have you tried these steps?